# Listview in Landscape (dual pane) disappers when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

In Landscape mode, my listview appears on the left side of the screen while the right side is blank, as it should be.  When user clicks an item, the details are displayed on the right side of the screen BUT the listivew disappears.  It seems to be acting like it's in portrait mode but it's clearly using the landscape xml layout-land.  After looking at dozens of examples, I still can't get the listview to remain on screen with the with the details.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Here's my code:

BookDetailsActivity:
    public class BookDetailsActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //** Getting the orientation ( Landscape or Portrait ) of the screen 
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    //** Landscape Mode 
    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ){
      //setting the landscape layout for this activity
      setContentView(R.layout.buy_tbfrag);

      //get fragment manager for fragment related operations
      FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

      //get fragment transaction object, which can add, move or replace a fragment
      FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

      //getting the existing detailed fragment object, if it already exists.
      //the fragment object is retrieved by its tag name
      Fragment prevFrag = fm.findFragmentByTag("book.details");

      //System.out.println("prevFrag = " + prevFrag);
      //** Remove the existing detailed fragment object if it exists */
      if(prevFrag!=null) {
          ft.remove(prevFrag);
      }

      //instantiating the fragment BookDetailsFragment
      BookDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new BookDetailsFragment();

      //creating a bundle object to pass the data (clicked item's position)
      //from this activity to fragment
      Bundle b = new Bundle();

      //setting the data to the bundle object from the Intent
      b.putString("load the bundle objects);
        ...

      //setting the bundle object to the fragment
      detailsFragment.setArguments(b);

      //adding the fragment to the fragment transaction
      ft.add(R.id.details_fragment_container, detailsFragment,"book.details");

      //add the fragment transaction to backstack
      //ft.addToBackStack(null);

      //Executing the transaction
      ft.commit();

    } else {
    ...
    start Portrait mode code...
    }
}
```

Buy_tbfrg xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/titleSearch"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_box"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3.97" >

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

BookDetailsFragment:
    public class BookDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_details, null);

       System.out.println("BookDetailsFragment executed");

      //Defines the TextViews in R.layout.book_details
      TextView bkTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
      ...

      //Retrieve the bundle object passed from BuyFragTab
      Bundle b = getArguments();


      //Getting the item's clicked position and setting corresponding details     
      //First check the bundle to ensure the data has been passed
      if (b != null) {
         bkTitle.setText    ("Title: " + b.getString("Selected_Title"));
        ...
      }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Loaders?. When initiating or restarting a Loader in the ListFragment or DetailFragment, make sure you pass different numbers (arg0).